# Views folder won't show in PhpStorm IDE, how do I make it viewable

Tags: phpstorm

I have a folder `src/Application/Sonata/SonataMediaBundle/Resources/views/` and it doesn't show in PhpStorm. The bundle was created using easy extends.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the folder in relation to your project root directory?

Comment: Goto `settings ==> directories` and set a valid resource root and check that the folder you're looking for has not been marked as hidden, etc. The folder will need to be within the resource root. Or add another resource root for this folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't show"? Some screenshots that would better clarify your situation are more than welcome. Whole IDE window ideally. Does such folder `views` folder will be shown if placed in another folder?

Comment: > 
Goto settings ==> directories  didn't solve

Comment: I just solved t his by 'removing the folder by command line' then adding the folder views again via the IDE.